# Is there a specific reason why we don't explicitly specify type of variable in csx scripts and use var at all times?

Tags: c#, .net, var, scriptcs, csx

I have been working very closely with csx lately and something that I noticed was that whenever we specify a variable it always used `var name = "Hello World";` instead of `string name = "Hello World";` . Is this due to a certain convention that developpers are expected when writting scripts or is there a more technical reason why var is used more often that specifying the actual type of the variable

Even in the scriptcs wiki (https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Writing-a-script ) which has some good content on csx , this nature of defining variables with var can be seen

So my question stands why do people always stick with var rather than specifying the variables such as string , int etc .

Comment: Because it’s easier to write and the type can be inferred. There’s no requirement for it, people are just used to it.

Comment: I  see ... So there is no such thing as performance of script would be better when using var over explicitly defining the variables and so on  right ?

Comment: var should be used when the type of the variable is obvious from looking at the right hand side of the assignment. e.g. `var a = "a string"`
If it isn't obvious a type should be used. e.g. `var score = game.score` vs `decimal score = game.score` The latter in this example is more explicit.
As per [Microsoft Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions#implicitly-typed-local-variables)

Comment: wow ! Thats some intersting information